# Property 'emp' does not exist on type 'employee[ ] - Angular 6 ng serve --prod

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular6, angular-material2

Running the command ng serve is working fine where as ng serve --prod shows error

```
ERROR in src\app\employee\employee.component.html(12,9): : Property 'emp' does not exist on type 'employee[]'.
src\app\employee\employee.component.html(23,9): : Property 'emp' does not exist on type 'employee[]'.
src\app\employee\employee.component.html(36,9): : Property 'emp' does not exist on type 'employee[]'.
```

Employee.component.html

```
    <h2 mat-dialog-title>Edit details</h2>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <form
    fxLayout="column"
    [formGroup]="editForm"
    #f="ngForm">
  <div class="input-row">
      <mat-form-field fxFlex>
        <mat-label>Id</mat-label>
        <input readonly 
        value="{{data.emp.id}}"
          matInput #id disabled
          formControlName="id"
          required/>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div class="input-row">
      <mat-form-field fxFlex>
        <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
        <input 
        value="{{data.emp.name}}"
          matInput #name
          placeholder="Email"
          formControlName="name"
          required/>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>

    <div class="input-row">
      <mat-form-field fxFlex>
        <mat-label>Designation</mat-label>
        <input
        value="{{data.emp.designation}}"
          matInput #designation
          placeholder="designation"
          formControlName="designation"
          required/>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>

    <br />
    <div class="">
      <button
        mat-raised-button
        type="reset"
        class="btn btn-danger width"
        (click)="close()">   Close</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <button
        mat-raised-button
        [disabled]="!f.valid"
        (click)="update(id.value,name.value,designation.value)"
        right
        class="btn btn-success width right"
        type="submit">
        Update
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <br />

</div>
```

Empoyee.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from "@angular/core";
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from "@angular/material";
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
import { HomeService } from "../home/home.service";


export interface employee{
  designation: string;
  id:number;
  name:string;
}
@Component({
  selector: "app-employee",
  templateUrl: "./employee.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./employee.component.css"]
})
export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {
  editForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EmployeeComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: employee[],
    private service: HomeService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.editForm = new FormGroup({
      id: new FormControl({ disabled: true }, Validators.required),
      name: new FormControl("", [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern(
          /^[A-Za-z]{1,16}([ ]?[a-zA-Z]{0,16})([ ]?[a-zA-Z]{0,16})$/
        )
      ]),
      designation: new FormControl("", [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern(
          /^[A-Za-z]{1,16}([ ]?[a-zA-Z]{0,16})([ ]?[a-zA-Z]{0,16})$/
        )
      ])
    });
    console.log(this.data);
  }

  update(id, name, designation) {
    console.log(this.editForm.value);
    this.service.updateEmployee(id, name, designation).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.dialogRef.close();
        console.log(data);
        console.log("done");
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }
  close() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

Mat Dialog data is coming from

Home.component.ts

```
 onEdit(emp) {
    console.log("row clicked");
    console.log(emp);
    this.employee1 = emp;
    console.log("clicked");
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EmployeeComponent, {
      width: "430px",
      data: { emp: this.employee1 }
    });
```

Everything is working fine while using ng serve but when using cmd ng serve 
--prod its showing error.

i tried this in employee.component.ts
id: employee[];
its not working

Comment: did you console.log 'emp'. It's only object or array of object.

Comment: array of objects

Comment: the console.log(emp) will give output as           {emp: {…}}
emp:
designation: "anilreddy"
id: 4
name: "anilreddya"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object

Comment: seems like its object instead of 'array of object'. declare employee1: employee;

Comment: its not working

Comment: create a stackblitz. will help to identify the issue.

Comment: Why are you injecting dialog data into a component instead of a dialog component?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this line:

```
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: employee[],
```

to

```
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
```

As data is not an employee array. it is an object which have employee array or employee object in your case. Tomorrow you can pass more objects in this data variable.

Comment: You can pass a data type for the dialog's data by passing in a [Union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) to `MatDialog#open`. See the source code for `MatDialog#open` for more info: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/d22f48c742c0bbdc971f79ea1261ec5c20d15a69/src/lib/dialog/dialog.ts#L127-L128 , as well as `MatDialogConfig`: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/d22f48c742c0bbdc971f79ea1261ec5c20d15a69/src/lib/dialog/dialog-config.ts#L83-L84

Comment: It doesn't seem the recommended way, but it works. Thanks!